What are f-wavefunction and d-wavefunction collapses?
It is found that for all the elements succeeding calcium the energy of 3d is less than the energy of 4s, I have heard this effect being termed as 'd-wavefunction collapse' here but I didn't understand it being explained as "the result of the interplay of nuclear attraction, of imperfect shielding by the inner-core electrons, and of angular-momentum dependent centrifugal forces." It would be much appreciated if someone could explain this more elaborately and more descriptively.
Similarly, what is the reason behind 'f-wavefunction collapse' which is used to explain why in lanthanum the 5d orbital is filled with 1 electron before the 4f-orbital here?
